# How to use gatling with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I am using Gatling for performance testing. I have one simulation as below:

```
private val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl(apiGatewayUrl)
    .acceptHeader("application/json")
    .header("A", "foo")
    .header("B", "bar")
    .header("C", "3")

private val success = scenario("successful scenario")
    .exec(http("collector")
        .post("/v1/events")
        .body(StringBody("""
            {
             body
        """.trimIndent())))

init {
    setUp(
       success.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(5.0).during(5),
           rampUsers(10).during(10),
           constantUsersPerSec(10.0).during(20)
       )
    ).protocols()
}
```

This code gived me compilation error:

Type mismatch.
Required:
List<io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder!>!
Found:
io.gatling.javaapi.core.PopulationBuilder

I was reading gatling docs and the examples seems to do in a similar way as above.

Comment: Where exactly is the error coming from? Can you also share the entire error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code you've provided is correct. I've injected it in the official  Gatling demo project for [gradle+kotlin](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-gradle-plugin-demo-kotlin) and it works fine (except for the missing `apiGatewayUrl` definition).

Possible explanation:

- wrong gradle project configuration
- wrong imports (missing from your sample)

Comment: seems like it was a wrong imports. After I fixed it, it worked with these imports 

import io.gatling.javaapi.core.CoreDsl.*
import io.gatling.javaapi.core.Simulation
import io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.http